# How can I show text over a ChartJS bar chart?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I need to write text into the bar in chart using chart.js

```
 var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
 var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
     type: 'bar',
     data:data,
     options: {           
         scales: {
             yAxes: [{
                 ticks: {
                     beginAtZero:true
                 }
             }]
         }
     },
     responsive : true,
     showTooltips : false,
     showInlineValues : true,
     centeredInllineValues : true,
     tooltipCaretSize : 0,
     tooltipTemplate : "<%= value %>"
 });
```

the code above do not working...

i need something like this:

[image: example]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this code to your options object:

```
animation: {
  onComplete: function () {
    var chartInstance = this.chart;
    var ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
    console.log(chartInstance);
    var height = chartInstance.controller.boxes[0].bottom;
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    Chart.helpers.each(this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
      var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
      Chart.helpers.each(meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
        ctx.fillText(dataset.data[index], bar._model.x, height - ((height - bar._model.y) / 2));
      }),this)
    }),this);
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h4p8f5xL/

UPDATE 2

Surround your canvas with a container with your desired width and height

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 500px">
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

and add the following into your options object

```
// Boolean - whether or not the chart should be responsive and resize when the browser does.
responsive: true,
// Boolean - whether to maintain the starting aspect ratio or not when responsive, if set to false, will take up entire container
maintainAspectRatio: false,
```

Comment: if you are on Google Chrome press F12 and go to the Console tab, see what is the output

Comment: the output of the canvas tag? <canvas id="myChart" width="1333" height="533" style="width: 1333px; height: 533px;">

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-ui?hl=en

Comment: hovering on the bar will yield a very bad effect. This is completely not acceptable.

Comment: The animation will be re-executed each time the tooltip is drawn. onComplete isn't an acceptable solution. An approach that uses plugins.afterDraw instead.

Answer (score 6):

If you would like to render centered text for each element, there is an easier way:

```
Chart.helpers.each(meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
    var centerPoint = bar.getCenterPoint();
    ctx.fillText(dataset.data[index], centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y));
}),this)
```

It seems that **'getCenterPoint' isn't available in version 2.1.3** (that you use in your example). I tried it with 2.5.0 and it works

Answer (score 1):

By now, a plugin is available that handles exactly this use case!

It's called chartjs-plugin-datalabels and documentation can be found here:
https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html